# Problem with converting Date and Time to Datetime Format

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, strtotime

everyone..

I'm on the way to find out why this code is not able to work :(

```
  $timeku = "3:00 PM";
  $dateku = "08/24/2011";
  $date_ku = explode("/",$dateku);
  $date_new = $date_ku[2]."-".$date_ku[1]."-".$date_ku[0];
  $datetime_ku = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($date_new.' '.$timeku));
```

every i try to insert data $datetime_ku to mysql database it always result : 1970-01-01 07:00:00

Why? and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$datetime_ku = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('08/24/2011'.'3:00 PM'));
```

Comment: yeah! got it! thanks mate! Do you know why my code doesn't works?

Comment: You forgot ; on the first two lines and structured $date_new = $date_ku[2]."-".$date_ku[0]."-".$date_ku[1]; wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Correct way to do the same

```
$date = new DateTime("$dateku $timeku");
$datetime_ku = $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo $datetime_ku;
```